# DIY wall anchor for speakers and stands

Tags: mounting, speakers

I have a pair of speakers that weigh 5.4kg/12lb each. They're mounted on a pair of DIY speaker stands. The stands are basically 2 pieces of oak connected with threaded rod that's covered by painted PVC pipe. The stands look great and have stood up well over the years, but they're not exactly what you'd call sturdy. Now the minor bumps and the occasional cat attacks that they've had to endure are starting to be augmented by a determined kid that is sure to topple them some time in the future, if left as is.

So ... the plan is to anchor both the speakers and stands to the wall. The speakers have both a keyhole mount and a threaded mounting hole, but I haven't seen a commercial mounting solution that I like (suggestions welcome, though). DIY seems like it would work, but I'm sort of stuck on what to build.

What I came up with is using heavier duty nailing plates/furniture corners and, using looped bolts, bolting a piece of threaded rod between them. So one end of the nailing plate into the wall/speaker, a looped bolt through the other end, a piece of threaded rod through the loop. Then strapping the stand to the mount with a steel strap and 3D printing some sort of cover to make it all look nice-ish. Not sure if it'd work well enough, though.

The solution should:

- Fail gracefully - eg. bend, if too much weight is put on the mount, instead of snapping.
- Allow some slight adjustment of the speaker. Swivel a few degrees at least.
- Allow mounting the speaker about ~10cm from the wall.

Other stuff:

- The walls are concrete.
- I have access to fairly basic metal parts from local hardware stores, no complicated custom shapes.
- I have a drill, so I can drill into metal and a jigsaw, so I can cut metal, albeit not precisely and nothing too thick.

Comment: A picture of your speaker & stand may help folks come up with ideas.

Comment: What's the point of the stands if your speakers are suspended anyway? I'd reconsider the potential clutter. And why doesn't the keyhole mount suit? One screw and you're done.

Comment: I'd take this opportunity to get the speakers up, off the floor and out of reach of curious little fingers that could poke holes in speaker grills and/or cones. Also, it should have the added benefit of getting them away from the malicious creatures you chose to let rule your house, protecting them from further damage by those spawn.

Comment: @isherwood, the short of it is that I simply like the stands. They fit the aesthetic of my other furniture and they hide the speaker wire. I'm not really willing to part with them. The keyhole mount is detrimental to the sound of this set, as they have the vent at the back. And they can't be mounted any higher than they currently are, as there's a window directly above one of them.

Comment: If you just want child safety, leash them instead of bolting (the speakers, not the kids). A small hook or picture hanger can handle the weight, as can a loop of 40lb fishing line running from wall hanger to the back of the speaker. It should be about invisible yet prevent smashed little feet and bonked heads.

Comment: Fair enough, but you could put some rubber or felt bumpers on the back and still use the keyholes.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility, if the speakers are small enough, is to not use the stands and use a small flat-panel monitor wall mount, something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KZP1BUI):

[image: wall-mount monitor plate]

Monitor mounts can mount to concrete walls, pivot and tilt, and some can come apart so the wall plate and device plate can be attached separately then attached on the wall.